# Different environments for Terraform (Hashicorp)

Tags: terraform

I've been using Terraform to build my AWS stack and have been enjoying it. If it was to be used in a commercial setting the configuration would need to be reused for different environments (e.g. QA, STAGING, PROD).

How would I be able to achieve this? Would I need to create a wrapper script that makes calls to terraform's cli while passing in different state files per environment like below? I'm wondering if there's a more native solution provided by Terraform.

```bash
terraform apply -state=qa.tfstate
```

Comment: https://github.com/unfor19/terraform-multienv - Since there's already an accepted answer and this question is quite old, I'm adding it here as a comment. I've created a template for maintaining a multiple environment infrastructure with Terraform. This template includes a CI/CD process, that applies the infrastructure in an AWS account.

Comment: http://github.com/unfor19/terraform-multienv  should be the answer now!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [hashicorp best-practices repo](https://github.com/hashicorp/best-practices), which has quite a nice setup for dealing with different environments (similar to what James Woolfenden suggested).

We're using a similar setup, and it works quite nicely. However, this best-practices repo assumes you're using Atlas, which we're not. We've created quite an elaborate `Rakefile`, which basically (going by the best-practices repo again) gets all the subfolders of `/terraform/providers/aws`, and exposes them as different builds using namespaces. So our `rake -T` output would list the following tasks:

```
us_east_1_prod:init
us_east_1_prod:plan
us_east_1_prod:apply

us_east_1_staging:init
us_east_1_staging:plan
us_east_1_staging:apply
```

This separation prevents changes which might be exclusive to dev to accidentally affect (or worse, destroy) something in prod, as it's a different state file. It also allows testing a change in dev/staging before actually applying it to prod.

Also, I recently stumbled upon this little write up, which basically shows what might happen if you keep everything together:
https://charity.wtf/2016/03/30/terraform-vpc-and-why-you-want-a-tfstate-file-per-env/

Comment: i feel like this is probably a better answer for a lot of folks.

Comment: Keeping a separate tfstate per environment is definitely a best practice - since Terraform 0.10, the [Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) feature does exactly this per 'workspace' (i.e. environment)

Comment: workspaces are not a suitable isolation mechanism for some scenarios. Please check it: "When to use Multiple Workspaces" https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html

Comment: Here workspaces are recommended in the developer's guide: https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/development/running-terraform-in-automation#multi-environment-deployment

Comment: Looks like the best practices repo is now deprecated

Comment: Some teams are also happy with terragrunt tool that does some "magic" on terraform files (rather than Rake).

Answer (score 18):

Paul's solution with modules is the right idea. However, I would strongly recommend *against* defining all of your environments (e.g. QA, staging, production) in the same Terraform file. If you do, then whenever you're making a change to staging, you risk accidentally breaking production too, which partially defeats the point of keeping those environments isolated in the first place! See [Terraform, VPC, and why you want a tfstate file per env](https://charity.wtf/2016/03/30/terraform-vpc-and-why-you-want-a-tfstate-file-per-env/) for a colorful discussion of what can go wrong.

I always recommend storing the Terraform code for each environment in a separate folder. In fact, you may even want to store the Terraform code for each "component" (e.g. a database, a VPC, a single app) in separate folders. Again, the reason is isolation: when making changes to a single app (which you might do 10 times per day), you don't want to put your entire VPC at risk (which you probably never change).

Therefore, my typical file layout looks something like this:

```
stage
  └ vpc
     └ main.tf
     └ vars.tf
     └ outputs.tf
  └ app
  └ db
prod
  └ vpc
  └ app
  └ db
global
  └ s3
  └ iam
```

All the Terraform code for the staging environment goes into the `stage` folder, all the code for the prod environment goes into the `prod` folder, and all the code that lives outside of an environment (e.g. IAM users, S3 buckets) goes into the `global` folder.

For more info, check out [How to manage Terraform state](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa). For a deeper look at Terraform best practices, check out the book *[Terraform: Up & Running](http://www.terraformupandrunning.com/)*.

Comment: Did you tried to enchance this solutin with a use of a modules to get rid of separate folder - separate state problem?

Comment: @aholbreich Yup, to avoid having to copy/paste the same code between each environment, we use modules as described here: [How to create reusable infrastructure with Terraform modules](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-create-reusable-infrastructure-with-terraform-modules-25526d65f73d).

Comment: @YevgeniyBrikman any recommendations for removing the 90% duplication of code from each environment? Each of mine are very similar and changing all is error prone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MikeD, I would say, you gotta modularize your code as much as possible to reduce such error

Answer (score 14):

Please note that from  version 0.10.0 now Terraform supports the concept of Workspaces (environments in 0.9.x).

A workspace is a named container for Terraform state. With multiple workspaces, a single directory of Terraform configuration can be used to manage multiple distinct sets of infrastructure resources.

See more info here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html

Comment: It is explicitly stated that Workspaces is not good solution for this problem - https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces

Answer (score 6):

As you scale up your terraform usage, you will need to share state (between devs, build processes and different projects), support multiple environments and regions.
For this you need to use remote state.
Before you execute your terraform you need to set up your state. 
(Im using powershell)

```bash
$environment="devtestexample"
$region     ="eu-west-1"
$remote_state_bucket = "${environment}-terraform-state"
$bucket_key = "yoursharedobject.$region.tfstate"

aws s3 ls "s3://$remote_state_bucket"|out-null
if ($lastexitcode)
{
   aws s3 mb "s3://$remote_state_bucket"
}

terraform remote config -backend S3 -backend-config="bucket=$remote_state_bucket"  -backend-config="key=$bucket_key" -backend-config="region=$region"
#(see here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/remote-config.html)

terraform apply -var='environment=$environment' -var='region=$region'
```

Your state is now stored in S3, by region, by environment, and you can then access this state in other tf projects.

Comment: there are much better ways to do this now, as a first step now id create a bucket without remote state as a first step and then add the remote after, That way you can at least manage the bucket with your TF process and theres no messing with the cli.

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no need for having separate codebases for dev and prod environments. Best practice dictates (I mean [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))  that actually you are better off having one code base and **simply parametrize it** as you would do normally when developing a software - you DONT have separate folders for development version of the application and for production version of the application. You only need to ensure right deployment scheme. The same goes with terraform. Consider this "Hello world" idea:

```
terraform-project
├── etc
│   ├── backend
│   │   ├── dev.conf
│   │   └── prod.conf
│   └── tfvars
│       ├── dev.tfvars
│       └── prod.tfvars
└── src
    └── main.tf
```

contents of etc/backend/dev.conf

```
storage_account_name = "tfremotestates"
container_name       = "tf-state.dev"
key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
access_key           = "****"
```

contents of etc/backend/prod.conf

```
storage_account_name = "tfremotestates"
container_name       = "tf-state.prod"
key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
access_key           = "****"
```

contents of etc/tfvars/dev.tfvars

```
environment = "dev"
```

contents of etc/tfvars/prod.tfvars

```
environment = "prod"
```

contents of src/main.tf

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 2.56.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "rg-${var.environment}"
  location = "us-east"
}
```

Now you only have to pass apropriate value to cli invocation, eg.:

```
export ENVIRONMENT=dev
terraform init -backend-config=etc/backends/${ENVIRONMENT}.conf
terraform apply -vars-file=etc/tfvars/${ENVIRONMENT}.tfvars
```

This way:

- we have separate state files for each environment (so they can even be deployed in different subscriptions/accounts)
- we have the same code base, so we are sure the differences between dev and prod are small and we can rely on dev for testing purposes before going live
- we follow DRY directive
- we follow KISS directive
- no need to use obscure "workspaces" interface!

Of course in order for this to be fully secure you should incorporate some kind of git flow and code review, perhaps some static or integration testing, automatic deployment process, etc. etc.. But I consider this solution as the best approach to having multiple terraform environments without duplicating code and it worked for us very nicely for a couple of years now.

Answer (score 3):

No need to make a wrapper script. What we do is split our env into a module and then have a top level terraform file where we just import that module for each environment. As long as you have your module setup to take enough variables, generally env_name and a few others, you're good. As an example

```hcl
# project/main.tf
module "dev" {
    source "./env"

    env = "dev"
    aws_ssh_keyname = "dev_ssh"
}

module "stage" {
    source "./env"

    env = "stage"
    aws_ssh_keyname = "stage_ssh"
}

# Then in project/env/main.tf
# All the resources would be defined in here
# along with variables for env and aws_ssh_keyname, etc.
```

Edit 2020/03/01

This answer is pretty old at this point, but it's worth updating. The critique that dev and stage sharing the same state file being bad is a matter of perspective. For the exact code provided above it's *completely* valid because dev and stage are sharing the same code as well. Thus "breaking dev will wreck your stage," is correct. The critical thing that I didn't note when writing this answer was the `source "./env"` could also be written as `source "git::https://example.com/network.git//modules/vpc?ref=v1.2.0"`

Doing that makes your entire repo become something of a submodule to the TF scripts allowing you to split out one branch as your QA branch and then tagged references as your Production envs. That obviates the problem of wrecking your staging env with a change to dev.

Next state file sharing. I say that's a matter of perspective because with one single run it's possible to update all your environments. In a small company that time savings when promoting changes can be useful, some trickery with `--target` is usually enough to speed up the process if you're careful, if that's even really needed. We found it less error prone to manage everything from one place and one terraform run, rather than having multiple different configurations possibly being applied slightly differently across the environments. Having them all in one state file forced us to be more disciplined about what really needed to be a variable v.s. what was just overkill for our purposes. It also very strongly prevented us from allowing our environments to drift too far apart from each other. When you `terraform plan` outputs show 2k lines, and the differences are mainly because dev and stage look nothing like prod the frustration factor alone encouraged our team to bring that back to sanity.

A very strong counter argument to that is if you're in a large company where various compliance rules prevent you from touching dev / stage / prod at the same time. In that scenario it's better to split up your state files, just make sure that *how* you're running `terraform apply` is scripted. Otherwise you run the very real risk of those state files drifting apart when someone says "Oh I just need to `--target` just this one thing in staging. We'll fix it next sprint, promise." I've seen that spiral quickly multiple times now, making any kind of comparison between the environments questionable at best.

Comment: Interesting. How do you keep the .tfstate files separated? Do you keep the environment specific modules in separate folders and keep associated .tfstate files in there?

Comment: Don't need to, one tfstate file for the entire aws account :) if you check your module into git, then you can set versions and branches for the envs. Just have to make sure you do a terraform get before each deploy to the non-dev envs.

Comment: Do you mean a `terraform refresh`?

Comment: If your `source` is anything other than a file path, you'll have to use `terraform get` to update those modules. During the first plan if you haven't done that it'll complain even for file path based modules.

Comment: Hi @Paul I haven't had time to look deeper into your answer. I don't quite understand how you can have one .tfstate file across all the different environments. If you ran `terraform apply` with the `dev` module, and then `terraform apply` with the `prod` module wouldn't it confuse itself? Or are you saying your .tfstate includes all resources across all your different environments?

Comment: So this solution is designed to have one tfstate file per AWS account you're trying to control. Each `module` you're calling from the top level `main.tf` file defines it's own VPC and the full set of machines that live in that VPC. The `tfstate` file doesn't care about how many objects are in there, and each VPC is still separate from every other VPC. `terraform apply` thus will apply updates to ALL the environments (since they're in the same AWS account) at the same time, which makes it easier to manager overall.

Comment: If you have a more than one environment (e.g. `dev` and `qa`) in the same AWS account and you're using one .tfstate, then sounds like all resources created across the different environments are stored in the one .tfstate file. I guess that works as a solution assuming that the resource names are unique across the different environments also. Is that how you things work for you Paul?

Comment: Yep. One thing to note, the only uniquely named resources that are required are the VPC's. Everything else is fine. In practice I use the env name as part of the resource name for everything, but it's not strongly required.

Comment: @Paul, could you please create a repository with sample codes in Github? It is big gap for understanding how make it work from your answer.

Comment: This will make all your environments share the same state file which is not a good pattern. You should have them separate. You have a limited control to rollout a change to stage after some time of testing in dev. And it is almost impossible to have different system accounts per environment. I've downvoted this answer because of these limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Form terraform version 0.10+ There is a way to maintain the state file using Workspace command

```
   $ terraform workspace list // The command will list all existing workspaces
   $ terraform workspace new <workspace_name> // The command will create a workspace
   $ terraform workspace select <workspace_name> // The command select a workspace
   $ terraform workspace delete <workspace_name> // The command delete a workspace
```

First thing you need to do is to create each workspace for your environment

```
   $ terraform workspace new dev
```

Created and switched to workspace "dev"!

You're now on a new, empty workspace. Workspaces isolate their state,
so if you run "terraform plan" Terraform will not see any existing state
for this configuration.

```
  $terraform workspace new test
```

Created and switched to workspace "test"!

You're now on a new, empty workspace. Workspaces isolate their state,
so if you run "terraform plan" Terraform will not see any existing state
for this configuration.

```
 $terraform workspace new stage
```

Created and switched to workspace "stage"!

You're now on a new, empty workspace. Workspaces isolate their state,
so if you run "terraform plan" Terraform will not see any existing state
for this configuration.

backend terraform.tfstate.d directory will be created

under them you can see 3 directory - dev, test,stage and each will maintain its state file under its workspace.

all that now you need to do is to move the env-variable files in another folder

keep only one variable file for each execution of terraform plan , terraform apply

```
   main.tf
   dev_variable.tfvar
   output.tf
```

Remember to switch to right workspace to use the correct environment state file

```
   $terraform workspace select test
   main.tf
   test_variable.tfvar
   output.tf
```

Ref : https://dzone.com/articles/manage-multiple-environments-with-terraform-worksp

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good answers in this thread. Let me contribute as well with an idea that worked for me and some other teams.

The idea is to have a single "umbrella" project that contains the whole infrastructure code.

Each environment's terraform file includes just a single module - the "main".

Then "main" will include resources and other modules

```
- terraform_project
- env
  - dev01        <-- Terraform home, run from here 
    - .terraform    <-- git ignored of course
    - dev01.tf  <-- backend, env config, includes always _only_ the main module
  - dev02
    - .terraform
    - dev02.tf 
  - stg01
    - .terraform
    - stg01.tf
  - prd01
    - .terraform
    - prd01.tf 
- main        <-- main umbrella module
   - main.tf
   - variables.tf         
- modules         <-- submodules of the main module
  - module_a
  - module_b
  - module_c
```

And a sample environment home file (e.g. dev01.tf) will look like this

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~>1.42.0"
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "tradelens-host-rg"
    storage_account_name = "stterraformstate001"
    container_name       = "terraformstate"
    key                  = "dev.terraform.terraformstate"
  }
}

module "main" {
  source               = "../../main"
  subscription_id      = "000000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000"
  project_name         = "tlens"
  environment_name     = "dev"
  resource_group_name  = "tradelens-main-dev"
  tenant_id            = "790fd69f-41a3-4b51-8a42-685767c7d8zz"
  location             = "West Europe"
  developers_object_id = "58968a05-dc52-4b69-a7df-ff99f01e12zz"
  terraform_sp_app_id  = "8afb2166-9168-4919-ba27-6f3f9dfad3ff"

  kubernetes_version      = "1.14.8"
  kuberenetes_vm_size     = "Standard_B2ms"
  kuberenetes_nodes_count = 4

  enable_ddos_protection = false
  enable_waf             = false
}
```

Thanks to that you:

- Can have separate backends for Terraform remote state-files per environment
- Be able to use separate system accounts for different environments
- Be able to use different versions of providers and Terraform itself per environment (and upgrade one by one)
- Ensure that all required properties are provided per environment (Terraform validate won't pass if an environmental property is missing)
- Ensure that all resources/modules are always added to all environments. It is not possible to "forget" about a whole module because there is just one.

[Check a source blog post](https://dev.to/piotrgwiazda/main-module-approach-for-handling-multiple-environments-in-terraform-1oln)

Answer (score 0):

Hashicorp recommends different statefiles and folders like this:

```
├── assets
│   ├── index.html
├── prod
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── variables.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   └── terraform.tfvars
└── dev
   ├── main.tf
   ├── variables.tf
   ├── terraform.tfstate
   └── terraform.tfvars
```

There's even documentation on how to refactor monolithic configuration to support multiple environments according to their best practice. Check it out here:
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/organize-configuration#variables-tf

Answer (score 0):

Example Run multiple examples

```html
├── env_vars
│   └── qa.tfvars
├── main.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── terraform.tfstate
├── terraform.tfstate.backup
├── _tools
│   └── apply.sh
└── variables.tf
```

You can run

```html
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your environment (qa,dev,stage or prod)"
read environment

rm -Rf .terraform/

terraform init -var-file=env_vars/$environment.tfvars #-backend-config="key=$environment/$environment.tf" -backend-config="bucket=<bucket_name>"
terraform apply -var-file=env_vars/$environment.tfvars
```